# Ошибка "Connection timed out" при подключению к TCP серверу используя мобильний интернет через смартфон

Tags: android, qt

Когда я подключаюсь к серверу через смарфон используя WiFi. То все работает без ошибок, но когда изменяю тип соединения на мобильний интернет то при попытки подключится к серверу видается ошибка "Connection timed out". Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить и возможно ли.
Зарание спасибо.

Код подключения к серверу:

```
QHostAddress address;
address.setAddress("192.168.55.102");
socket->connectToHost(address, 2323);
QByteArray arrByte;
QDataStream out(&arrByte, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

out << quint16(0) << 36 << 1 << 1;

out.device()->seek(0);
out << quint16(arrByte.size() - sizeof(quint16));
socket->write(arrByte);
```

Comment: Код покажи как ты коннектишся

Comment: Код подключения к серверу добавил к вопросу.

Comment: При подключении по WiFi Вы находитесь в одной сети с узлом `192.168.55.102`, а при мобильном подключении — в сети оператора. Естественно, что из нее Ваш серый IP `192.168.55.102` не виден. Решение — подключаться к внешнему IP Вашей сети, и на роутере пробросить нужный порт (`2323`, судя по приведенному коду) на адрес `192.168.55.102`.